# Coverting Int64index to list or accessing list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists but because of the Int64Index I cannot access it. Is there a way to access individual values or make it into a normal list?

```
data_exp = pd.read_csv(path+'/exp.csv')

exp_list=[]

for i in range (1,n+1):
    check=data_exp.apply(lambda x: True if x['Set No.']==i else False, axis=1)
    temp=[data_exp[check==True].index+1]
    exp_list.append(temp)
del temp

display(exp_list)
```

The for loop just sort values based on a condition. The output is good but it is the format which is problamatic.

Gives me out put as follows:-

```
[[Int64Index([8, 11, 17, 20, 21, 27, 29, 36, 37, 38], dtype='int64')],
[Int64Index([1, 3, 7, 10, 14, 31, 33, 34, 35], dtype='int64')],
[Int64Index([5, 9, 12, 15, 19, 23, 25, 26, 28, 32], dtype='int64')],
[Int64Index([2, 4, 6, 13, 16, 18, 22, 24, 30, 39, 40], dtype='int64')]]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're doing to get the list of Int64Indexes, but you can access the numpy array underlying the index with the values property:

```
from pandas import Int64Index

l = [[Int64Index([8, 11, 17, 20, 21, 27, 29, 36, 37, 38], dtype='int64')],
[Int64Index([1, 3, 7, 10, 14, 31, 33, 34, 35], dtype='int64')],
[Int64Index([5, 9, 12, 15, 19, 23, 25, 26, 28, 32], dtype='int64')],
[Int64Index([2, 4, 6, 13, 16, 18, 22, 24, 30, 39, 40], dtype='int64')]]

print(l[0][0].values[0])
```

Comment: Thank you John M. It worked perfectly. But I found the error in the code as well. I had used '[ ]' Square brackets while assigning value to 'temp' in for loop. I just removed it. It still gives me the same output as in the question. But it is now accessible in the normal method of accessing values.  l[0][0]

Comment: That's good news. Glad you got it sorted out.